# Which countries can I travel with a German emergency passport?

Tags: usa, passports, canada, germany

How many countries can I travel to with a temporary passport (1-year validity). I would like to travel to the USA and Canada, but I'm not sure if it's OK to travel there with a temporary passport, because I can't get the normal passport for now.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What's your actual question, here. "How many countries?" doesn't seem like it's much use to you -- suppose the answer is 28: then what? Also, are you asking literally about the number of countries, or about the total number of trips? It's probably better to limit your question to just "Can I go to the USA and Canada?"

Comment: Why can't you get a new passport?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can look up entry requirements for all countries on the website of the [German Federal Foreign Office](https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/de/ReiseUndSicherheit/reise-und-sicherheitshinweise). For example, entering the USA on a temporary passport [is only possible if you have a visa](https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/de/usavereinigtestaatensicherheit/201382#content_3), so you can't use ESTA in this case and have to apply for a visa at the US embassy/consulate instead. Canada on the other hand [allows](https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/de/kanadasicherheit/204874#content_2) eTA even with a temporary passport, so you don't need a visa there.